# Ubuntu 12.04 Not booting from USB

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, usb, ram

I recently made my USB bootable with Universal USB installer and changed the boot priority settings in bios..but when i restarts my pc my old xp loads.

What can I do to boot the USB stick?

My Pc Config : 1.25GB RAM
               INTEL 845G MOTHERBOARD
               P4 2.4GHz
               500GB HDD

Answer (score 1):

have You tried pressing [ F9 / F2 / F1 ] at the time of boot ( very initial stage of booting) .. One of them is supposed to give you a list of available boot drive options.. Like Pendrive , USB , CD/DVD.

Comment: Also try **Esc** at boot time.  Basically, read the onscreen prompt ..

Comment: Thnx guys but i used plop boot manager ..